# LinearLayout not measuring TextView inside

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` with square `ImageView` inside and a `TextView` under it. This is my row layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my java code to prepare the `RecyclerView`

```
categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

but the `ImageView` is taking whole row layout and the text is not showing.
[image]
How can I set priority or something like this to views in `LinearLayout`?

And here is the `add shell dumpsys activity top` result:

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{bd92bdf VFED..... ........ 0,450-1440,1352 #7f09003a app:id/categoryRecyclerView}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{44fd02c V.E...... ........ 989,0-1440,451}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{5713af5 V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{faaf08a V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{5cea6fb V.E...... ........ 989,451-1440,902}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{ffc318 V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{6e79171 V.ED..... ......ID 193,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{d4f8b56 V.E...... ........ 538,0-989,451}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{1d6b7d7 V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{bb9f8c4 V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{392d3ad V.E...... ........ 538,451-989,902}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{6d106e2 V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{be4fa73 V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{cbfdd30 V.E...... ........ 87,0-538,451}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{635fda9 V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1fcaf2e V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{18acacf V.E...... ........ 87,451-538,902}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{cfd9c5c V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{8c7cb65 V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{228903a V.E...... ........ -364,0-87,451}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{e1344eb V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{5f62248 V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
         android.widget.LinearLayout{3eeb8e1 V.E...... ........ -364,451-87,902}
           com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView{7ff7606 V.ED..... ........ 32,32-419,419 #7f090075 app:id/image}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{c5f44c7 V.ED..... ......ID 295,435-419,435 #7f0900d1 app:id/text}
```

Comment: can you show a screenshot?

Comment: have you tried buy setting image view width and height. because if the image is bigger in size it will occupy the entire row

Comment: @Manojkumar aggree with you

Comment: it's not definitive and layout is changing based on other elements on the screen and screen size @Manojkumar

Comment: I've edited my question @VladMatvienko

Comment: when you give wrap content to any image view it will completely cover the content width and height. @Amir_P so the width and height have to be set to the image view

Comment: whats the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`? post just `RecyclerView` and its child views

Comment: please check question again @pskink

Comment: then see the first `AppCompatTextView`: it has `295,435-419,435` so left=295, top=435, right=419, bottom=435 - it means that top == bottom so most likely no `setText` was called (or with null/empty text)

Comment: when I'm setting width and height of `ImageView` text is showing correctly @pskink

Comment: so what does `SquareImageView#onMeasure` look like?

Comment: What I have done is to calculate in code how much should be the width of the image. I got the total of pixels of the screen and then subtracted the padding or margin I had and the result divided by the number of columns I had.

Comment: it's just `int width = Math.min(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(width, width);` @pskink

Comment: do you know what is `widthMeasureSpec` / `heightMeasureSpec`? did you read `View.MeasureSpec` javadocs?

Comment: i've been using `getMeasuredWidth()` but no difference :D @pskink

Comment: did you read `View.MeasureSpec` javadocs? or not?

Comment: no i didn't @pskink

Comment: so do that and then you will be able to implement `onMeasure` in a right way

Comment: and what do you see if you call `Log.d` with `View.MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec)` and `View.MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec)` ?

Comment: it's a big negative number at first but then different numbers `height: MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 288, width: MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 387, height: MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 387,width: MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 65472,height: MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 288,width: MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 387,...`

Comment: so `387` is what your `SquareImageView` should pass to `setMeasuredDimension` method

Comment: isn't it should be 288? the min number of width and height? and also can we talk about it in chat? @pskink

Comment: ok ask google for `square view onMeasure` and you will know what to do

Answer (score 1):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <com.myCompany.myProject.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight=1 />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Square image view class is like this

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(height , height);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Lets make use of layout weight in `LinearLayout`. What it will do is setting priority to the `SquareImageView` and so much of the part is taken by it. Do not get suprised but we will set the height to `0dp` to improve perfomance. Go on add this attributes to the `SquareImageView`.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this

//customrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
  >
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="20dp"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imggridicon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/book"/>
            <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txticdgridmaintitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="20dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

//Layout Manager

```
 GridLayoutManager lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(Activity_Grid_Main_Home.this, 2);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainhome_recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
```

Comment: i don't want to set width and height of my `ImageView`

Comment: you can set the width as wrap_content. In my case all images were different in dimension.

Comment: if you hard code the width and height you can set the scaleType as well.